# What is the loss function used in Trainer from the Transformers library of Hugging Face?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

What is the loss function used in Trainer from the Transformers library of Hugging Face?

I am trying to fine tine a BERT model using the **Trainer class** from the Transformers library of Hugging Face.

In their [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer), they mention that one can specify a customized loss function by overriding the `compute_loss` method in the class. However, if I do not do the method override and use the Trainer to fine tine a BERT model directly for sentiment classification, what is the default loss function being use? Is it the categorical crossentropy? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends!
Especially given your relatively vague setup description, it is not clear what loss will be used. But to start from the beginning, let's first check how the default `compute_loss()` function in the `Trainer` class looks like.

You can find the corresponding function [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.17.0/src/transformers/trainer.py#L2006), if you want to have a look for yourself (current version at time of writing is 4.17).
The [actual loss that will be returned with default parameters](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.17.0/src/transformers/trainer.py#L2026) is taken from the model's output values:

> `loss = outputs["loss"] if isinstance(outputs, dict) else outputs[0]`

which means that the model itself is (by default) responsible for computing some sort of loss and returning it in `outputs`.

Following this, we can then look into the actual model definitions for BERT (source: [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.17.0/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py), and in particular check out the model that will be used in your Sentiment Analysis task (I assume a [`BertForSequenceClassification` model](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.17.0/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1501).

The [code relevant for defining a loss function](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.17.0/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1563-L1583) looks like this:

```py
if labels is not None:
    if self.config.problem_type is None:
        if self.num_labels == 1:
            self.config.problem_type = "regression"
        elif self.num_labels > 1 and (labels.dtype == torch.long or labels.dtype == torch.int):
            self.config.problem_type = "single_label_classification"
        else:
            self.config.problem_type = "multi_label_classification"

    if self.config.problem_type == "regression":
        loss_fct = MSELoss()
        if self.num_labels == 1:
            loss = loss_fct(logits.squeeze(), labels.squeeze())
        else:
            loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
    elif self.config.problem_type == "single_label_classification":
        loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
    elif self.config.problem_type == "multi_label_classification":
        loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
```

Based on this information, you should be able to either set the correct loss function yourself (by changing `model.config.problem_type` accordingly), or otherwise at least be able to determine whichever loss will be chosen, based on the hyperparameters of your task (number of labels, label scores, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. I am planning to fine tune this [open source model pretrained BERT model on Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/yiyanghkust/finbert-pretrain) for sentiment analysis. And you are right that I am planning to use the BertForSequenceClassification model. I think the problem is multi_label_classification (3 labels with one of the label is the correct one for each observations), and the BECWithLogitsLoss should be able to serve the purpose. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for a great answer @dennlinger I am actually trying to finetune startcoder model for code autocompletion and also using Trainer and using AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path) I aslo find it hard to find the default loss func in the source code. https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.30.0/src/transformers/models/auto/modeling_auto.py#L1117
maybe you will have any insight on this?

Comment: I think this merits its own question @Rachel Shalom.