# How to add weights in BERT loss function

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, sentence-transformers

I have unbalanced dataset size N with such classes:

- class 1 - size 0.554*N
- class 2 - size 0.271*N
- class 3 - size 0.185*N

I’m trying to solve NER task by fine-tuning Bert “dslim / bert-large-NER”, but during training my eval f1 score doesn’t rise above 0.53

How to add weights in BERT loss function to overcome low f1 score?

I tried to fine-tune other ner models from huggingface, but they didn't help

I use Trainer from Transformers to train the model

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you compute the loss?

Comment: Actually there is no code for loss function. It is automatically computed in Trainer from Transformers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before the Bert loss function is [defined by the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71581197/what-is-the-loss-function-used-in-trainer-from-the-transformers-library-of-huggi). If you want to modify loss function, you need to define the Bert class again. For example:

```
class Bert_modified(BertForTokenClassification):

    def forward(*some input parameters*):

        *important class code*

         loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights_tensor)
         loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))

        *important class code*
```

Bert's classes in Transformers you can find [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/v4.17.0/src/transformers/models)